# Cleaning Data With Regex in Excel-VB

Tags: excel, vba

I've had need to clean up some types of special characters from files before loading them into a processing system that is used at my workplace.  I'm using the following script that I created, but it utilizes a loop and it's pretty inefficient.  A file of around 100,000 rows will take 5-10 minutes to run through the script.

Can anyone suggest a more efficient solution? I'm generally more comfortable with regular expressions, but it isn't necessary if there's a better way that I can ensure characters such as line breaks, line feeds, and other characters that I might define at a later time can still be removed.  But it's probably overkill for the need.  Still, it would probably work much faster if I didn't have to use a loop to loop through each row/column.

```
Function ApplyPattern(WordString, Pattern, ReplaceWith)
    Dim RegEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    RegEx.Pattern = Pattern
    RegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    RegEx.Global = True
    RegEx.MultiLine = True
    ApplyPattern = RegEx.Replace(WordString, ReplaceWith)
End Function
Sub CleanFile()
'
'This process cleas the data within a worksheet using the regex pattern defined below
'
Dim NumRows As Long 'Declare NumRows variable
Dim NumCols As Integer 'Declare NumCols variable
Dim Pattern As String

Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z_0-9\.\t)(,# ]"

Cells(1, 1).Select 'Selects first row of worksheet

'Find the number of rows
NumRows = Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
'Find the number of columns
NumCols = Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column

'Loop for cleaning data
For TargRow = 1 To NumRows
    Cells(TargRow, NumCols + 1).Value = TargRow 'Adds a row number for later use
    For TargCol = 1 To NumCols
        Cells(TargRow, TargCol).Value = ApplyPattern(Cells(TargRow, TargCol).Value, Pattern, "") 'Applies the regex pattern to the cell
    Next TargCol
Next TargRow

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: I can't completely disagree with you on the `RegEx` as it's pretty much the go-to guy for tasks like this, but perhaps adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end can shave off time?

Comment: Thanks, great idea.  It helped!  It shaved off at least a couple of of minutes run time on my test case.